# hdiutil not finishing (UDRW)

Tags: terminal, macos

I'm trying to convert a .iso to a .img using

```
server:~ user$ hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.dmg ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso 

Usage:  hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>
        hdiutil convert -help
```

Every time I run the command it creates the file on the desktop, then when it finishes running the file's gone. It's clear that there is an error somewhere, but I get no information.

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to juggle the order of things:

```
hdiutil convert ~/whatever.img -format UDRW -o ~/destination.iso
```

I may be wrong, but top of my head I see that...

Comment: No luck, I've checked the md5 and everything fine. Any other ideas?